# How can I use tags to know what picture box it corresponds to?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I've made a system of coordinates in an 8x8 grid of picture boxes using tags. If I have the tag I want to be able to know what picture box that the tag corresponds to. I'm finding it difficult to explain but this is my best attempt.

The tags consist of an x and y coordinate (x, y).

I've thought about making a bunch of if clauses but I'm guessing that there has to be another way.

Comment: So you have a tag with coordinates and want to find the matching picturebox?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In winforms i would use a TableLayoutPanel with 8 columns and 8 rows (if this can change, then make it programmatically). Then just put into the cell the right picturebox. Then, to grab the picturebox you could use something like myLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(x,y);

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Control? GetControlFromPosition (int column, int row);
```